# Why is the correct phrase "to come on the trip" and not "to come to the trip"?

Tags: prepositions, idioms

I wrote the following:

> I was surprised Mary had agreed to come to the trip.

A native English speaker told me I should write instead:

> I was surprised Mary had agreed to come **on** the trip.

I admit it surprised me. I could have sworn it was **to**. Why is it **on** instead of **to**? How can I avoid making this mistake in the future?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "Why" is easy: because we have held repeated elections and for several centuries *on* has always won.

As far as avoiding the mistake, it may help you to consider, first, that *to* generally indicates a trip's destination, not the trip itself; and second, that we use *on* in many constructions which designate presence or motion on (!) a path:

> Point A lies **on** the curve defined by ...
>   **On** the road again ... —song by Willie Nelson
>   Soybean prices are **on** a downward trajectory.
>   She's **on** her way to the top.
>   The road goes ever **on** and **on** ... —song by J.R.R. Tolkien

Comment: +1 because the critical part of the distinction is **motion**.  We go **to** events with a static location -- such as dinner, a conference, a meeting (the location of which will be designated by **at**, for example, _dinner at the hotel_ or _a meeting at the downtown conference center_ ; or **in**: _We have a meeting in (not at) the conference room_ if it is in our office building.  Of course there will be things that don't fit like the locative usage of **on** such as _the book is on the table_.  Some things you just have to memorize until you have enough examples to construct a rule.

Answer (score 4):

Check this definition, [on](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/on) sense 9:

> 9) engaged in   ⇒ "on a trip"

Here *trip* refers to an activity, not a location, so *on* is correct.
In the case of a location, you could say:

> I was surprised Mary had agreed to come **to the beach**.

Comment: @StoneyB Oh thanks, I think the confusion arose because I was thinking about trip as a location rather than an activity, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To is used when referring to a specific point or location. A trip is not either, rather being an activity involving places.

I go TO London.
I go ON a trip TO London.
I will be going TO London ON the trip.

Answer (score 1):

"To" refers to **location.** "On" (in this context) refers to **direction.**

A trip has a direction, not a location. Therefore you use "on."